# Cron expression for Databricks schedule job

Tags: cron, databricks

I need to schedule a job in databricks that should run at 6am, 6.15, 6.30, 6.45, 7, 7.15, 7.30, 7.45 and 8am every day.

I am using below expression however it is not running at 8am. Is there anyway we can achieve this?

0 0,15,30,45 06,07 ? * *

Comment: Can anyone please help here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behaviour from cron expression. As per your requirement, you need to write separate cron expression for the 08:00 as follows:

> Note that some scheduling requirements are too complicated to express
>   with a single trigger - such as “every 5 minutes between 9:00 am and
>   10:00 am, and every 20 minutes between 1:00 pm and 10:00 pm”. The
>   solution in this scenario is to simply create two triggers, and
>   register both of them to run the same job.

This will run from 6.00 until 7.45, every 15 minutes:

```
* 0/15    06-07       *     *   *
```

If you want it to run until 08:00 then you have to create two triggers and register both if them to run the same job.

```
* 0/15    06-07      *     *    *     
*  0       08        *     *    *
```

**Reference:** Databricks uses Quartz Cron triggers. [Databricks – Cron Triggers](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.7/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT. Unfortunately databricks is not accepting two line for cron syntax.

Comment: So, you need to create a seperate trigger at 8:00.

Comment: The solution in this scenario is to simply create two triggers, and register both of them to run the same job.

Comment: Thank you, i was looking for a solution that avoids creating two jobs. But looks like that's the only solution available. I do not see anyway to create two triggers in databicks. Need to create two jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Run twice a day at 10:00 and 18:00

```
0 0 10,18/12 * * ?
```

http://www.cronmaker.com/;jsessionid=node01kfgs14jy2pa91nxvfa6fs3vnr2008805.node0?0